# Javascript counter variable not displaying correct value

Tags: javascript

I have a global counter variable that when I call it inside the HTML im not getting the updated value.  I am only getting the instantiated value.
When I call it I always get 1.  I need it to display 2,3,4,etc....

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 1;
    function moreFields() {
      counter++;
      var newFields = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
      newFields.id = '';
      newFields.style.display = 'block';
      var newField = newFields.childNodes;
      for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
        var theName = newField[i].name
        if (theName)
          newField[i].name = theName + counter;
      }
  </script>
</fieldset>
<span id="writeroot"></span>
<fieldset id="readroot" style="display: none">
  <legend>Options For FieldSet # <script> document.write(counter.value);</script></legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Why do you expect the counter to ever increase?

Comment: Just in the edit alone, I see a syntax error (missing `}` before closing `</script>`).

Comment: I have a code that calls moreFields().  So the counter is supposed to increase.  if I do a write on the function it does increase, but on the html call in the legend I need it to display the current counter.  I always get 1

Comment: If you're not providing all the code, you're not going to get an accurate answer. But, from what it sounds like, you're writing counter out before the function is called and since it's not tied to any updates, it's never going to change as `counter` is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brad Christie commented,
`document.write(counter.value);` only happens once and it is happening before function `moreFields()` is being called.

Instead, I would suggest creating a span (or basically any html element for that matter) inside of the `legend` tag.

For example:

```
<legend>Options For FieldSet # <span id="counterDisplay"></span></legend>
```

You could then access the div by its class and update the value whenever necessary.

For example, in the beginning of your code you could do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 1;
    document.getElementById("counterDisplay").innerHTML = counter;
```

Likewise, within the function `moreFields`, you could do:

```
function moreFields() {
    counter++;
    var newFields = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
    newFields.id = '';
    newFields.style.display = 'block';
    var newField = newFields.childNodes;
    for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
        var theName = newField[i].name
        if (theName)
            newField[i].name = theName + counter;
    }
    document.getElementById("counterDisplay").innerHTML = counter;
}
```

Finally, you could rewrite your block of code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 1;
    document.getElementById("counterDisplay").innerHTML = counter;
    function moreFields() {
        counter++;
        var newFields = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
        newFields.id = '';
        newFields.style.display = 'block';
        var newField = newFields.childNodes;
        for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
            var theName = newField[i].name
            if (theName)
                newField[i].name = theName + counter;
        }
        document.getElementById("counterDisplay").innerHTML = counter;
    }
</script>
<span id="writeroot"></span>
<fieldset id="readroot" style="display: none">
    <legend>Options For FieldSet # <span id="counterDisplay"></span></legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I have a button on top of the fieldset that calls the moreFields() function.  The counter gets updated when it is called and if I do a write inside the function I get 2,3,4,etc.  I just need to get the same value on the html side

     <li><input type="button" id="addMoreFields" onclick="moreFields();" value="Add another Trunk Group" /></li>

Comment: That's what I'm showing with creating a div inside of the legend tag and calling document.getElementById("counterDisplay").innerHTML = counter; to update the value shown.

Comment: Probably better to use a span than a div though, and set `newFields.style.display = '';` rather than `'block'`.

Comment: ya, I hear you. I'm trying to only slightly modify the code to answer the question asked.

Comment: the above code doesnt work I still keep getting the 1 when I click the ""addMoreFields" button.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console? Can you post more of your code so that we can see what is causing the problem?